# binary addition of two numbers with wrap-around c++

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

day before i asked a question regarding the addition of two binary numbers. my problem was solved. the value is C is fine but now i am facing trouble in wrap-around. To handle a wrap-around value I have created another array S and copy value of C (obtained by binary addition of A and B) in S. The addition is performed until carry becomes zero. the value is copied fine but after changing S garbage value is saved in S. I don't know whats wrong. can anyone help please. thanks in advance. Here's the code

```
char C[9]={'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
char B[9]={'1','1','0','0','0','1','1','1','\0'};
char A[9]={'1','1','0','0','0','0','1','1','\0'};

char carry='0';
char sum[9]={'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    C[i] = ((A[i] ^ B[i]) ^ carry); 
    carry = ((A[i] & B[i]) | (A[i] & carry)) | (B[i] & carry);
}

strcpy(sum,C);
for(int l = 7; carry!='0'; l--) {
sum[l] = (C[l]) ^ (carry);
carry = C[l] & carry;
}

cout << endl << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Why are you adding characters instead of numbers?

Comment: i tried using integers but i was not getting fine output :( the ORing was not giving appropriate results

Comment: What if `l` becomes negative before `carry` becomes `'0'`? Will it *ever* become `'0'` and not `0` (those are not the same)?

Comment: Also, I recommend you step through the code line by line, in a debugger while keeping an eye on all variables.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg its not possible i guess. even adding biggest numbers yields a zero. so while wrap-around carry will become zero

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i checked everything. value of C[l], carry but the XORing results are not expected :( XORing returns garbage value

Comment: Why don't you put a `cout << sum << ' ' << carry << '\n';` into the for loop and show us the output?  "garbage values" often aren't garbage - they're just something that you don't understand how you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should simply use integers instead of char. Something like the following.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  int B[8]={1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1};
  int A[8]={1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1};

  int carry=0;
  int sum[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
      sum[i] = ((A[i] ^ B[i]) ^ carry); 
      carry = ((A[i] & B[i]) | (A[i] & carry)) | (B[i] & carry);
  }

  if ( carry ) {
    int carryArray[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1};
    carry = 0;
    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
      sum[i] = ((A[i] ^ carryArray[i]) ^ carry); 
      carry = ((A[i] & carryArray[i]) | (A[i] & carry)) | (carryArray[i] & carry);
    }
  }

  for(int l = 0; l < 8; l++) {
    cout << sum[l];
  }

  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok let me try. till this step char array was ok. I was having trouble in wrap-around. but let me try first

Comment: @sara What do you mean by wrap-around?

Comment: the carry generated in first step will add in the sum

Comment: Then sum shall have another digit to it. However it just has 8 locations.

Comment: No the sum generated by adding A & B is stored in C. in wrap-around carry will add in sum (solution will remain 8 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use bitwise operators only (you may consider right and left shifts) and operate over integers.

Problem is that you are operating over ASCII value of 0 and 1, not on 0 and 1. So subtract/add '0' wisely.

```
char carry='0';
char sum[9]={'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};

for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    C[i] = ((((A[i] - '0') ^ (B[i] - '0')) ^ (carry- '0'))) + '0'; 
    carry = ((((A[i] - '0') & (B[i] - '0')) | ((A[i] - '0') & (carry - '0'))) | ((B[i] - '0') & (carry - '0'))) + '0';
}

strcpy(sum, C);

for(int l = 7; carry != '0'; l--) {
    sum[l] = ((C[l] - '0') ^ (carry - '0')) + '0';
    carry = ((C[l] - '0') & (carry - '0'))+ '0'; //be careful about operator precedence.
}
```